# Splitting binary tree code does not work on some cases

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to solve a problem of Splitting Binary Tree in python. I will post the problem statement.

> Write a function that takes in a Binary Tree with at least one node and checks if that Binary Tree can be split into two Binary Trees of equal sum by removing a single edge. If this split is possible, return the new sum of each Binary Tree, otherwise return 0. You don't need to return the edge that was removed.

The testing code is somewhat like this

```
import program
import unittest


class TestProgram(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self):
        tree = program.BinaryTree(2)
        tree.left = program.BinaryTree(4)
        tree.left.left = program.BinaryTree(4)
        tree.left.right = program.BinaryTree(6)
        tree.right = program.BinaryTree(10)
        tree.right.left = program.BinaryTree(3)
        tree.right.right = program.BinaryTree(3)
        expected = 16
        actual = program.splitBinaryTree(tree)
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

and my code for splitBinaryTree is following

```
# This is an input class. Do not edit.
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


def splitBinaryTree(tree, balancesum=0):
    # Write your code here.
    if tree is None:
        return 0
    fullsum = icalculatesum(tree)
    print('fullsum is', fullsum, 'balancesum is', balancesum)
    if fullsum == balancesum:
        return fullsum
    leftsum = icalculatesum(tree.left)
    rightsum = icalculatesum(tree.right)
    if leftsum+tree.value == rightsum+balancesum:
        return fullsum/2
    if rightsum+tree.value == leftsum+balancesum:
        return fullsum/2
    if leftsum+tree.value+balancesum == rightsum:
        return fullsum/2
    if rightsum+tree.value+balancesum == leftsum:
        return fullsum/2
    lefty = splitBinaryTree(tree.left, fullsum-rightsum)
    righty = splitBinaryTree(tree.right, fullsum-leftsum)

    if lefty != 0 or righty !=0:
        return fullsum/2
    return 0


def icalculatesum(node, sumsofar=0):
    if node == None:
        return sumsofar
    sumsofar += node.value
    sumsofar = icalculatesum(node.left, sumsofar)
    sumsofar = icalculatesum(node.right, sumsofar)
    return sumsofar
```

I am having problem in the following test case. Answer should be 70 but mine is 0

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "1", "left": "9", "right": "20", "value": 1},
    {"id": "9", "left": "5", "right": "2", "value": 9},
    {"id": "20", "left": "30", "right": "10", "value": 20},
    {"id": "30", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 30},
    {"id": "10", "left": "35", "right": "25", "value": 10},
    {"id": "35", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 35},
    {"id": "25", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 25},
    {"id": "5", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 5},
    {"id": "2", "left": "3", "right": null, "value": 2},
    {"id": "3", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 3}
  ],
  "root": "1"
}
```

I am practicing on a leetcode like platform. Please tell me where am I going wrong, and if any information needed I will be glad to try to answer.

I tried removing condition that previously existed

```
if fullsum%2 !=0:
return 0
```

because i am recursing it. Eventually it will reach odd number and return False/0.

Comment: `icalculatesum` doesn't add the sums of the left and right subtrees.

Comment: in all the test cases i checked the printed sum was accurate atleast for the root case, and i thought the sumsofar keptupdating in icalculatesum. where do you think is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The way you create the sum is a bit unusual in my opinion so I didn't realize how it works.

Comment: is it because i pass it as well? to keep track of it? what would be the usual way? and no apologies needed, thanks for trying to respond.

Comment: I figured it out but i need to understand and i hope someone can explain this. i added more conditions like


        return totalsum/2
    if leftsum  == node.value + rightsum + balancesum:
        return totalsum/2
    if rightsum == node.value + leftsum + balancesum:
        return totalsum/2


for a solo nodes that are equal to the rest of sum of subtree i think

Comment: Passing `sumsofar` as argument to `icalculatesum` seems uncommon to me. Usually you would just add up sums of node and left and right subtree in the function. This result is the node value sum of the tree or subtree for which `node` is the root, so it works recursively, too.

Comment: I have problems to understand your general approach, especially the meaning of `balancesum`. The problem statement can be simply rewritten as "Check if there is a subtree with a node sum `== fullsum/2`". Assuming that all node values are non-negative, you can ignore subtrees with node sum `< fullsum/2` and only have to recursively search subtrees with node sum `> fullsum/2`.

Comment: So my thought process behind balancesum was that there is total sum which is sum of the whole root, and so when you recurse on a left or a right child, you need to remember the sum of the rest of the tree and see if it matches when you try to break the edge. Does it make sense? if you recurse on the right subtree, the balance sum is the rest of the sum and the right subtree sum and if its equal then we can split on that edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

This comparison:

```
    if leftsum+tree.value == rightsum+balancesum:
        return fullsum/2
```

...seems to cut *two* edges: it extracts the `tree` together with its left subtree, so `tree` is detached from both its parent and its right child. So this is not correct. The next `if` block has the same problem, but mirrored. These two `if` blocks should be removed from your code.

The following two `if` blocks do it correctly, as there the `tree` is not detached from its parent, but only from one of its children (but you don't need these blocks either as explained below).

The recursive calls provide a wrong value for the second parameter: the value of `tree` itself is not accounted for. So this:

```
    lefty = splitBinaryTree(tree.left, fullsum-rightsum)
```

...should really be this:

```
    lefty = splitBinaryTree(tree.left, balancesum  + tree.value + rightsum)
```

Same fix should be applied for `righty`.

Note that the corrected expression is the same as you used in the `if` blocks discussed earlier. And that is why also those `if` blocks can be  omitted. Those cases will be captured one level deeper in recursion.

The final statements can be simplified to just `return lefty or righty`.

With those fixes your code will look like this:

```
def splitBinaryTree(tree, balancesum=0):
    if tree is None:
        return 0
    fullsum = icalculatesum(tree)
    if fullsum == balancesum:
        return fullsum
    leftsum = icalculatesum(tree.left)
    rightsum = icalculatesum(tree.right)
    lefty = splitBinaryTree(tree.left, balancesum  + tree.value + rightsum)
    righty = splitBinaryTree(tree.right, balancesum + tree.value + leftsum)
    return lefty or righty
```

#### A more efficient algorithm

The approach you have taken is not efficient. All you really have to do is find a subtree whose sum is half the total sum. The edge that is cut is the one that has the root of this subtree as its child. This pattern fits all possibilities: all edges (parent,child) have the root of a subtree as child.

Secondly, if you calculate the sums *incrementally*, from the bottom up, you'll only visit a node once, giving a time complexity of O(). Once you have collected these sums -- in this bottom up approach -- it is trivial to solve the challenge.

#### Code

```
# Recursively collect all tree sums into a list, with the root's sum listed first
def getAllTreeSums(tree):
    if not tree:
        return [0]
    left = getAllTreeSums(tree.left)
    right = getAllTreeSums(tree.right)
    return [tree.value + left[0] + right[0], *left, *right]

def splitBinaryTree(tree):
    tree_sums = getAllTreeSums(tree)
    if tree_sums[0] % 2 == 0 and tree_sums[0] // 2 in tree_sums:
        return tree_sums[0] // 2
    return 0
```

Comment: I have a question in the part where you are telling me whats wrong with my code. In the second point, you say my code should be 

    lefty = splitBinaryTree(tree.left, fullsum-rightsum-tree.value)


why are we removing tree.value? shouldn't it be added since its the rest of the sum of the tree

Comment: I subtracted `tree.value` because you started from `fullsum`, which when I look at it now makes little sense. So, yes, you should add `tree.value`, but not to `fullsum`, but to `balancesum`. I edited my answer with this info and a bit more.